# Implement a specific Spring Security filter for a particular REST controller

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-data

I have several REST controllers, among one is `/api/test`. Now, I have a `MyCustomFilter` class that extends `OncePerRequestFilter`.

```java
public class SecurityConfig {

    private final UserServiceImplementation userServiceImplementation;
    private final JwtAuthFilter jwtAuthFilter;
    private final TimingFilter timingFilter;
    private final ApiRateLimit apiRateLimit;
    private final MyCustomFilter myCustomFilter;

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean(AuthenticationConfiguration configuration) throws Exception {
        return configuration.getAuthenticationManager();
    }
    @Bean
    public AuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider() {
        final DaoAuthenticationProvider provider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        provider.setUserDetailsService(userServiceImplementation);
        provider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
        return provider;
    }
    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .cors(cors -> cors
                        .configurationSource(request -> new CorsConfiguration().applyPermitDefaultValues()))
                .csrf(crsf -> crsf
                        .disable())
                .authorizeHttpRequests(authz -> authz
   
                        .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/v1/user/hotel").permitAll()



                        .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.GET,"/api/test").permitAll()

                        .anyRequest().permitAll())
                .exceptionHandling( ex -> ex
                        .authenticationEntryPoint(new JwtAuthenticationEntryPoint()))
                .sessionManagement(session -> session
                        .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS));

        http.authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider());
        http.addFilterBefore(apiRateLimit, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
        http.addFilterBefore(timingFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
        http.addFilterBefore(jwtAuthFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);

        http.addFilterBefore(myCustomFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);

        return http.build();
    }


}

    @Component
public class MyCustomFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {


    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {
        System.out.println("My custom filter is called");
        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
    }


}
```

Whenever I hit endpoints like `/v1/user/hotels` or others,
`MyCustomFilter` is applied to them as well. However, **I only want this filter to be applied to specific endpoints, such as `/api/test`.**
How can I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

If Spring recognizes your filter during its component scan, the filter will get automatically added to the base SecurityFilterChain and thus to all `FilterChains` (and their endpoints). If that is not what you want, you have to remove `@Component` from your filter and inject it manually into the chain:

```java
@Bean
public SecurityFilterChain apiTestFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

    return http
            .securityMatchers(matchers -> matchers
                        .requestMatchers("/api/test/**")),

            //...
            .addFilterBefore(new MyCustomFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)

            .build();
}
```

Notice the extra `SecurityFilterChain` which shall be placed in front of your regular ones, since it filters out only calls to `/api/test/**` via `.securityMatchers`. You can adjust all requirements specifically for this endpoint. eg. the `Filter` you wanna place.

Answer (score 0):

You can override the method `shouldNotFilter` from `OncePerRequestFilter`. For example, the following code will make sure that your filter will work only with `GET` method to `/api/test`. You might need to update your matcher, but I hope that you get the idea.

```
private final RequestMatcher requestMatcher;

public MyCustomFilter() {
    this.requestMatcher = 
        new AntPathRequestMatcher("/api/test", "GET");
}

@Override
protected boolean shouldNotFilter(HttpServletRequest request) {
    return !requestMatcher.matches(request);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your question. However, won't it be overwhelming when we have many endpoints to include in the list of antPathMatchers by iterating through every endpoint,
will it be a good approach? just my question

Comment: In this case, you can use OrRequestMatcher to combine many enpoints. You can also check other matchers in the same package - org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher